# How to drip-feed/schedule a Google Sheets script for http status on multiple urls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-codes

I have a google sheets script setup that checks multiple urls for their http server status.

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

Then in my spreadsheet I have:

___________ A ___________| __________ B __________           |

[www.mysite.com/mypage1](http://www.mysite.com/mypage1) __|   "=getStatusCode(A1)"

[www.mysite.com/mypage2](http://www.mysite.com/mypage2) __|   "=getStatusCode(A2)"

and so on...

A the moment, the script runs on all cells as soon as I open the sheet (and there's lots of them). Is there any way on arranging this so it performs the script on a handful of cells on a schedule/limit of my choosing? The most ideal option would be to tell it to run the script on cell A1 then pause for a specified amount of time before running it on cell A2 etc..

Comment: The problem is that a custom function must finish execution within 30 seconds else it will fail. UrlFetchApp is slow and sleeping between calls will add to the problem. Would running this on a button click instead of onOpen be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Alternatively you could run the function on a minute trigger and update only one cell per minute?

Comment: @Rafa Yes a button click would be acceptable. How could I implement this?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo That would be perfect. I just don't know how to set this up. Would I need to edit the script first before setting up a trigger? (as the script doesn't specify any cells/range)

Comment: How many rows do you have? That will determine whether a button or a trigger would be better suited.

Comment: it can be anything up to a few hundred

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the number of calls to external endpoints by utilizing the [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache). You should probably also make your custom function work with arrays so that it can fill the whole column with one call like `=getStatusCode(A1:A)`. See Google's [custom function optimization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization) page for more info.

Comment: I don't really want to cache the results as I need real live results at the time. I want to focus more on a time delay per x number of rows kind of solution. If that is possible. To help with limiting the number of calls I could utilise more columns if needed (i.e. 1 column per batch).

Comment: You can use a short cache expiration time if you are concerned about outdated results — that would probably get you fresher results than sleeping between calls. In any case, the second bit about working with arrays will probably have more impact.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can use a minute trigger to run one query per minute, using `PropertiesService` to store how far you've gone through the sheet.*

#### More Information:

`PropertiesService` is a class which allows you to store information within a script so that it can be accessed on each run. This means you can retain information/variables across runs, even after the script has finished execution.

The idea is as such:

- Create a property store which saves the last row that the script ran on
- On each run, check the property store. If there is a last row saved, run the script on the next row, and save the new last row to the property store.
- If the current row is empty, assume we have hit the end of the sheet and delete the property store.
- If there is no property store, start from the beginning of the sheet again
- Run the script once per minute, so each status code retrieval will be staggered

#### Code Example:

```js
// Copyright 2021 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Define your sheet so it can be accessed from all functions
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
// Don't forget to change your sheet name:
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

// This is the function to run on minute trigger
function onMinuteTrigger() {
  // Define the property service and check if there is a last row saved
  const sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
  let row = sp.getProperty("last")

  // if there was no last row, set the 'row' variable to 0
  if (!row) row = 0

  // add 1 to row so the script runs on the next row, not the last
  row++
  
  // call the status code function
  const statusCode = getStatusCode(row)
  // if the statusCode is null then the row was blank; 
  // so delete the property store and return
  if (statusCode == null) {
    sp.deleteProperty("last")
    return
  }

  // if the script has got this far there was a returned status code
  // save the status code to the sheet and save the new last row
  // to the property store
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(statusCode)
  sp.setProperty("last", row)
}
```

Along with a slightly modified version of your `statusCode()` method:

```js
// modified statusCode function from your question
// pass to it the row to update
function getStatusCode(row) {
  const options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'followRedirects': false
  }
  // manually get the url from the passed row variable
  const url_trimmed = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue().trim()

  // if url_trimmed is blank then the row is empty, return null
  if (url_trimmed.length == 0) return null
  
  // fetch the URL and return the response code
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options)
  return response.getResponseCode()
}
```

#### References:

- [Class PropertiesService | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)
- [Installable Triggers | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)